# What programming language, algorithm should I use for dictionary translation?

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, dictionary

I need to translate (or rather, map) the words in an English document to Bengali using an English-to-Bengali dictionary. I have a huge collection of these documents. What algorithm should I use, and what language? The documents and dictionary are UTF-8 encoded text files. The translation is naive and straightforward, as words will be blindly replaced with whatever the dictionary says, be it a single-word meaning or a phrase or a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any mainstream language you want. Just check what sort of support it has for unicode and whether it has a built in associative data structure (e.g. `stl::map` in C++, `HashMap/TreeMap` in Java, `dict` in Python etc.). Pretty much any modern language has them, or has a freely available library for them.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any mainstream language. If time is short I'd stick with python. If you have time and want to make excellent money with your coding skills (should you chose to develop them) I'd go with c#

Comment: Could you also suggest the algorithm to use; a straight forward hash-table lookup?

Comment: A simple Dictionary<string,string> is all you need :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx